# N1QL REST API always return error on base SELECT

Tags: couchbase, sql++

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 94256359-1d49-d10d-d674-ee3cb57c8235" -d 'statement=SELECT text FROM weets LIMIT 1' "http://localhost:8093/query/service"
```

The response is:

```
{
    'requestID': '5d839aab-64c6-4c84-b89d-3d8137e19cf4',
    'errors': [
        {
            'code': 3000,
            'msg': 'syntax error - at SELECT'
        }
    ],
    'status': 'fatal',
    'metrics': {
        'elapsedTime': '830.837µs',
        'executionTime': '746.072µs',
        'resultCount': 0,
        'resultSize': 0,
        'errorCount': 1
    }
}
```

I tried to query data through Couchbase REST API but struggles to make a successful request.
I understand what does the error mean but cannot understand what's wrong with the query. Anyone who's familiar with couchbase n1sql please help.
I appreciate.

Comment: it works for me with Couchbase Server 4.5, which version are you using? I wonder if getting rid of the `statement=` would work better?

Comment: I'm using Version: 4.5.0-2601 Enterprise Edition (build-2601)

Comment: that's weird, I literally just copied your curl command and just changed `weets` to `default` and it worked for me, same Couchbase version...

Comment: it's working now after i created index of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query works fine for me. Try running it through the cbq tool and see if it works there! ( http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/tools/cbq-shell.html#topic_bzd_zwr_w5 ).

Also you can try wrapping the bucket name with backticks (`) like *SELECT text FROM `weets`*